# Bootstrap Image Gallery - open modal image in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-image-gallery

So with the Bootstrap Image Gallery addon created by Sebastian Tschan we can open images in a modal window and we can use slides or buttons to load up the next or previous images but there is an extra event action (left mouse button click on the loaded image) that does the same as "next" button (it loads up the next image) This function is a bit useless for me, so I thinking on modifying this click event, adding a better functionality to it.

Question is: How can I open the currently seen/loaded image in a new window with this event like HTML target="_blank" ?

Comment: Your modal Html and js code in next page and openmodal in document.ready function and give link previous page with target=_blank.